# EntityFramework Foreign Key conflict with optional value

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, annotations, foreign-keys

I have users and cars. Each user can be assigned to one specific car and vice versa, but this is not mandatory.

My 2 classes look like this:

```cs
public class User
{      
    [ForeignKey("Car")]
    public int? CarId { get; set; }
    
    public Car? Car { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Car
{      
    public User? User { get; set; }

    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now to the problem: As soon as I save it (doesn't matter if it is update or add), I get the exception `The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_User_Car_CarId". The conflict occurred in database "test-db", table "dbo.Car", column 'Id'.`

I tested around a little bit and saw that the CarId is set to the value 0 instead of null. Therefore, I added this line, before I call the update or delete method.

```cs
user.CarId = user.CarId == 0 ? null : user.CarId;
await this.Context.Set<User>().AddAsync(user);
await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

```cs
user.CarId = user.CarId == 0 ? null : user.CarId;
this.Context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
this.Context.Update(user);
await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Now to the weird part, since this still did not work. I set a breakpoint to the first line of either of the two methods and step over each line. As soon as I either call `Update` or `AddAsync`, the CarId becomes 0 instead of null, after the call of said methods. Therefore, the call of `SaveChangesAsync` gets the conflict.

Is there something I completely missed? My `DbContext` is basically empty, since I only use code first data annotations.

Comment: Do you need the CarId Property in your model or did you just add it to realize the relation between Car and User? Because if it is the latter you don't need to specify the foreign key property explicitly in your model. You can omit the CarId property, as EF will generate this as a shadow property for you to realize the Car navigation property

Comment: @TostMaster: Removing the ID worked, but what if I would need the ID?

Comment: You can get the ID by following the navigation property. Do something like `MyUser.Car.Id`. This will work because the User's Car's Id is the same as the User's CarId